# Which SQL Server sql data type to use in order to preserve UTC date time

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, entity-framework-4, utc

I have a SQL Server DB table that has a column "ReceivedDate" defined as "datetime" which should contain UTC date...In my C# code I use Entity Framework to map to table to a class, which has a corresponding property "ReceivedDate" of type System.DateTime.

The program loads the date from an XML file into DB and at some point later checks if the data in XML is same as data in DB...The check fails when dates of ReceivedDate in XML and DB don't match...For example:

```
ReceivedDate from XML:
<ReceivedDate>2010-12-16T22:53:27.5912217Z</ReceivedDate>

ReceivedDate from DB:
2010-12-16 22:53:27.590
```

After some debugging I noticed that date from DB does not have Kind property set to Utc and the number of ticks is much less and therefore comparison on dates fails...

- How do I store full UTC date in SQL
  server so when Entity Framework
  retrieves it, I get System.DateTime
  value that is exactly same as the one
  from XML file (including Kind=Utc)?
- Is this just a matter of using
  different sql data type for my column
  (e.g. datetime2 istead of datetime)?

---

### Update:

The way I resolved this was to:

1. change sql data type to "datetime2" to match precision between sql data type and .net System.DateTime
2. in my POCO I overrode Equals and when checking ReceivedDate property I just created another DateTime variable from ReceivedDate but using constructor with Kind == Utc.

This works, although I do agree that using DateTimeOffset would probably be better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` in Sql server only has [an accuracy of one three-hundredth of a second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

The accuracy in .Net is higher. The DB data is therefore rounded, and not the same. If you look at your data, the error is 0.0012217 seconds.

If possible, you could use the [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx):

> 0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default precision is 7 digits.

`datetime2` uses the same accuracy as the .Net `DateTime`.

Comment: As I suspected (in my question), precision is one part of the issue...Changing to "datetime2" helped, however entity framework still does not set the Kind property to "Utc" (according to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/49d68ea5-f44f-4f08-a4e4-ce4612f4876d)

Comment: thanks for clarification. I am setting your reply as answer as it matches my use case more closely. However, if I had a choice to change my domain model I would have gone with @Oded answer as DateTimeOffset is probably more elegant solution.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`datetimeoffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) to store on SQL Server.

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.

Also, consider using the [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure instead of `DateTime` in your .NET code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option for me...Domain model property is set to System.DateTime and if I use "datetimeoffset", as you pointed out, I would have to use System.DateTimeOffest...I need a solution to preserve UTC with DateTime (if possible)

Comment: It appears that the `DateTimeOffset` struct is only useful if you *have* the offset: i.e. you are using SQL's `DateTimeOffset` or you know the UTC DateTime **and** the time zone. But +1 for a really viable option for people developing/revamping new stuff.

Comment: @zam6ak, then your domain model is wrong. EF 4 supports `DateTimeOffset`. Update your model.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz sometimes, in real life, you just can't change the domain model (in my case domain model has been established some years ago)...

Comment: @zam6ak: Then you don't need to (EF) map to it directly. You can map to the correct type and project onto your domain model in object space.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz I took a bit of a different approach which still solves my issue although not as elegant as using DateTimeOffset. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn your database UTC `DateTime`s into C# `DateTime`s, do this. When you create the `DateTime`, use the constructor with the `DateTimeKind` parameter:

```
DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(((DateTime)row["myUtcDateTime"]).Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

If you're looking for a better way to actually **store** it in SQL (and you're on 2008), follow @Oded's advice.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I am using Entity Framework, so my domain model is being "managed" by EF - I am not "loading" the date myself...

Comment: @zam, ah... well..... So much for Entity Framework being better than sliced bread!

Comment: @zam6ak, @Brad: If you insist on using the wrong data types -- both EF and SQL Server support `DateTimeOffset`, which you *should* use if you intend to mix heterogeneous time zones -- you can still write equivalent code with EF projections. But if you want it to be *automatic*, then you must use the correct types.

Comment: @Craig, I definitely agree that using `DateTimeOffset` in both cases (SQL and .NET) is the best route.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz I agree with you also, but as I mentioned my domain model is "set in stone" (a collection of POCOs) and I cannot change it, so I have to work with DateTime.